# IQueryable selecionar dados de múltiplas tabelas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, query, linq-to-entities

Tenho um queryable (*linq to entities*) no EntityFramework e não estou conseguindo puxar dados de duas ou mais tabelas.

Por exemplo:

```
var model = _service.List().Where(m => m.DS_GRUPO.Contains(searchString)).Select(m => new { m.PK_GRUPO, m.DS_GRUPO, m.SUBGRUPO.DS_SUBGRUPO }).ToList();
```

Aqui faço uma busca e a partir do resultado da busca eu seleciono apenas os dados que vou utilizar, são eles: as propriedades **m.PK_GRUPO** e **m.DS_GRUPO** estão OK, ambas são do tipo string já a **m.SUBGRUPO** é um ICollection da classe SubGrupo e preciso pegar também **m.SUBGRUPO.DS_SUBGRUPO** que não estou conseguindo.

Alguem sabe como posso pegar essa outra propriedade?

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem essa parte aqui:

```
var model = _service.List()...
```

Mas suponho que deva ser uma chamada ao contexto, já que você colocou que o código funciona em Entity Framework.

O comando em teoria está certo. Faltam alguns incrementos. Vou tomar algumas liberdades pra fornecer uma resposta que esteja mais alinhada com o modo padrão de uso do Entity Framework:

```
var model = context.Grupos
                .Include(m => m.Subgrupo)
                .Where(m => m.DS_GRUPO.Contains(searchString))
                .Select(m => new { m.PK_GRUPO, m.DS_GRUPO, m.SUBGRUPO.DS_SUBGRUPO })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: O método Include não aparece! O povo aqui no serviço utiliza serviço que instancia um repositório. Por isso _service.List().

Comment: Entendi. Algum método devolve um `DbSet`? Você pode colocar na sua pergunta a implementação do repositório?

Comment: Já descobri o erro, eu fiz uma confusão na criação dos parâmetros. No caso preciso listar da Grupo e não na SubGrupo, pois a Grupo que deve conter uma lista de sub grupos. Obrigado de qualquer maneira! Como devo proceder para finalizar essa pergunta? Solicito a exclusão ou posto a resposta?

Comment: @Trxplz0 Poste sua resposta e a marque como aceita.